# SSMA for MySQL painfully slow when moving data to SQLAzure

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-migration-assi

I'm trying to move data over from MySQL to SQLAzure. The "[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL v5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26712)" tool has been invaluable in getting the structure and most of the data translated/moved, but we have one table that's, well, large.

Moving the records from the MySQL instance to the SQLAzure instance seems to be taking about 1 second per record and the records are (on average) about 35 kB in size.

If I look at the SQL Azure management tool, it doesn't seem to be under ANY load, same for MySQL. Similarily, the network connection from here is barely spiking at all. Does anyone have any idea what the bottleneck might be, and what I can do about it?

Comment: If Azure has a management console like MSSQL, you could just try dumping that table to a normal .sql file, then paste it into the management console's query window and execute it directly. Of course, if "large" means multi-gigs, that's not particularly practical.

Comment: "Large" is more like 450 MB... still more than I want to try to dump in by hand.

Comment: What about importing your records in SQL Server first, then use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard or the Enzo Data Copy (both free tools) to move that data to SQL Azure?  It's an extra hop indeed...

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Project Settings', first set the 'Batch size' value to '2147483647' which is its maximum allowable value and set the 'Parallel data migration mode' to 'Custom' and, lastly, set the 'Tread Count' to '50' or '100' would improve and speed up the data migration time immensely.

[image: Project settings]